# Pyinstaller can't create .app on mac

Tags: macos, python-3.5, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I create a small app using PyQt5.9.

when I run

> python3 setup.py bdist_mac

to create an .app on mac, I got following error.

```
copying /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore -> build/exe.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/QtCore
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore'
```

I used

- python3.5
- cx_freeze
- PyQt5

Please help me